# How to add CMS like menu in easy admin bundle

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have entity Page, Menu and MenuItem. All of it combined should render me a menu in cms like way. Here are entities:

Page:

```
**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="page")
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $content;
}
```

MenuItem

```
class MenuItem
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var Menu
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Menu")
     */
    private $menu;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      max = 255
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     */
    private $position;


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Page")
     */
    private $page;
}
```

Menu

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="menu")
 */
class Menu
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MenuItem")
     */
    private $items;
}
```

All I want to do is way to add Menu in easy admin bundle with creating a repeater of menu items where can I select existing page and enter position number. 
I tried to make it like this:

easy_admin_bundle.yaml

```
- { property: 'items', type: 'App\Form\MenuType' }
```

But I dont know how to make a form to be like reapeater one with adding new section or removing existing one.

Answer (score 0):

What is the base for MenuType? I think it should be EntityType, and the class should be MenuItem, but as far as I know EasyAdmin handles that by itself. Also see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#class

If you want to add a group of fields, make it a CollectionType based MenuItemsType, with the entry_type set to MenuType and add multiple fields in MenuType, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-type